# ¿Cómo generar una lista desplegable a partir de una una función con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-select

tengo esta página HTML y necesito generar una lista desplegable a partir de una función y según el arreglo, establecer el valor para el atributo `value` debe ser el correo electrónico y la opción para elegir debe ser el nombre de la persona, todo con jQuery.

He tratado de hacerlo de muchas formas, sin embargo, no he tenido éxito en poder resolverlo.
¿Saben de algún tema en especifico que me ayude a realizarlo?

Adjunto el código y gracias de antemano.

```js
//datos de las personas guardadas en un arreglo
var personas = [
['Carlos García', 'cargarcia@tec.mx','T', '1985', 'C. Básicas',   'AGVR600509R6T','-'], 
['Cristy Zerweck','cristyz@tecma.mx','E', '2014', 'IGE', '--', '96'],
['Jorge Martínez','majorge@tecma.mx','E', '2015', 'ISC', '--', '98'],
['Jesús Valdés',  'jesusvald@tec.mx','T', '2001', 'Mantenimiento','EVCU801125UY7','-'], 
['Maky Guajardo', 'mguajar@tecma.mx','E', '2013', 'ISC', '--', '97'],
['Nohemí Gámez',  'luisa.gam@tec.mx','T', '2000', 'Financieros',  'OGME790413HG3','-'], 
['Sergio Salazar','sergiosal@tec.mx','T', '1990', 'Planeación',   'ESRA701230Q23','-'], 
['Víctor Luévano','vluevanos@tec.mx','T', '1996', 'Gestión Tec.', 'ILVI720809MWE','-'], 
['Vita Torres',   'vtorres@tecma.mx','E', '2014', 'ITIC','--', '94'],
['Zulema Gómez',  'zulemag@tecma.mx','E', '2016', 'ITIC','--', '97'],
['Ludwing Miranda', 'lmiranda@tecma.mx','E','2018', 'ISC','--', '95']];
//agrega tus datos al arreglo anterior para que también aparezcas en la lista desplegable

//arreglo para guardar los objetos
var apersonas=[];

//prototipo para crear los objetos
function Persona (nombre, email, tipo, anio, area, rfc, prom) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.correo = email;
    this.tipo   = tipo;
    this.ingreso= anio;
    this.antiguedad= function () {
                return (new Date().getFullYear() - this.ingreso);
        }
    this.area = area;
    this.rfc = rfc;
    this.promedio=prom;
}

//función para crear los objetos y guardarlos en un arreglo
function creaPersonas(arreglo){
    for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        nombre=arreglo[i][0];
        email =arreglo[i][1];
        tipo  =arreglo[i][2];   
        anio  =arreglo[i][3];
        area  =arreglo[i][4];   
        rfc   =arreglo[i][5];
        prom  =arreglo[i][6];
        apersonas.push(new Persona(nombre, email, tipo, anio, area, rfc, prom));
    }
    return;
}

// La función generaLista(arregloObjeto) crea la lista desplegable a partir del arreglo de objetos.
// En la lista, el valor para el atributo value debe ser el correo electrónico. 
// En la lista, la opción para elegir debe ser el nombre de la persona. 
function generaLista(arregloObjeto) {
    
}


// La función accionChange() busca en el arreglo de objetos a la persona elegida de la lista desplegable.
// Muestra los datos de la persona dependiendo su tipo (trabajador o estudiante)
// El acceso al DOM debe hacerse con jQuery. 
function accionChange() {
    
}
```

```css
body {
    font: 100% sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1.0625em;
}

p { width: 80%; }

.tabla {
    width: 38em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #336699; 
    font-size: .8125em;
    text-align: left;
}

.titulo {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.20em 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #5C85AD;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

.enca { /*para el th */
    padding: .5em .15em .5em 1.0em;
}

.campo-medio {
    /*width: 150px;*/
    width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Trabajadores y Estudiantes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="comun/css/estilo-p33.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- genera el enlace al archivo script-p31.js -->
    <!-- genera el enlace al framework de jQuery (jquery.min.js) 
         la llamada al fremwork puede ser local o al servidor remoto-->
</head>
<body>
<p>El trabajador es la persona física que presta sus servicios de manera retribuida a otra persona, a una empresa o a una institución.</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>
    <label>Persona: <select>
        <option value="">Seleccione persona</option>
    </select></label>
    <script>
        // realiza la llamada al script que genere la lista desplegable
    </script>
</p>
<p></p>
<table class="tabla">
    <tr><th colspan="4" class="titulo"><span id="dnombre">-</span></th></tr>
    <tr><th class="enca">e-mail:</th><td><span id="dmail">-</span></td>
        <th><span id="trfc">R.F.C.:</span></th><td><span id="drfc">-</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th class="enca"><span id="tarea">Depto.:</span></th><td><span id="darea">-</span></td>
        <th><span id="tprom">Promedio:</span></th><td><span id="dprom">-</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th class="enca">A. Ingreso:</th><td><span id="dingreso">-</span></td>
        <th>Antigüedad:</th><td><span id="dantigue">-</span></td></tr>
</table>
<script>
    // realiza la llamada al script de jQuery para que al momento de seleccionar un
    // elemento de la lista desplegable se muestre sus datos en la tabla

</script>
<script src="./comun/js/script-p33.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el html debes darle un id al select

```
<p>
    
    <label>Persona: <select id="selectNumber"><option value="">Seleccione persona</option></select>
    <script>
        // realiza la llamada al script que genere la lista desplegable
    </script>
</p>
```

Luego en el Javascript debes tener algo que te ayude a agregar las opciones que serán tomadas del arreglo de arreglos llamado personas:

```
for(var i = 0; i < personas.length; i++) { 
    var opt = personas[i][0]; 
    var el = document.createElement("option"); 
    el.textContent = opt; 
    el.value = opt; 
    select.appendChild(el); 
    
}
```